# Sending a php $Array using an input hidden

Tags: php, html

i sending the values of an Array in php from a php file to another, and i am using an input hidden with seriaize, it works fine, but i read on a web page that i can use serialize when the array has not a lot of values just when it has a few values, i dont know,  for example an array[10] or [8], and I using this array to save a lot of values, like 40 or more, and i want to make sure that serialize() will work fine on that, what do you think?, can I use serialize with a lot of values inside an array?

My code here:

```
////file1.php////

//here both $code_period and $selection are array, and i dont know exactly how many values i will
//save inside them   

echo "<form name='formprocess' method='post' action='process.php'>

<input name='code_period_name' type='hidden' value='".serialize($code_period)."'>
<input name='selection' type='hidden' value='".serialize($selection)."'>

<input style='background:#13284B;color:White' type='submit' value='Process'>

</form>";



////process.php////

$code_period_name=unserialize($_POST['code_period_name']); //im catching these values this way
$selection=unserialize($_POST['selection']);
```

Like I said before, It works just fine I just wanna know your opinion about this, cause i read on a web page that i can use serialize when i have to save a few values

Comment: This can also be saved as a session I guess?

Comment: How would you do that buddy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd do is not `echo` out huge chunks of static HTML.

The second thing I'd do is the following...

```
<form name="formprocess" method="post" action="process.php">

<?php foreach ($code_period as $val) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="code_period_name[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($val) ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php foreach ($selection as $val) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="selection[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($val) ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>

<button type="submit">Process</button>

</form>
```

Then, when you access `$_POST['code_period_name']` or `$_POST['selection']`, they will already be arrays.

Comment: Great buddy,  Do you think serialize() works fine on big arrays?, arrays with a lot of values?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't but I feel it would be better to work with scalar values and not have to parse / decode / unserialise data at both client and server ends

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to json format and send it you can again decode it back to get the same array

```
echo "<form name='formprocess' method='post' action='process.php'>

<input name='code_period_name' type='hidden' value='".json_encode($code_period)."'>
<input name='selection' type='hidden' value='".json_encode($selection)."'>

<input style='background:#13284B;color:White' type='submit' value='Process'>

</form>";

In Process.php
$code_period_name=json_decode($_POST['code_period_name']); //im catching these values this way
$selection=json_decode($_POST['selection']);
```

Comment: Great buddy, Can i use json to work with big arrays?, arrays with a lot of values?